# How can I automatically rebind bootstrap tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

Using [twitter bootstrap tooltips](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), I can do something like

```
$('.tooltip-enabled').tooltip();
```

which works fine for `<div id="1234" class="tooltip-enabled"</div>`.

But, if I then do `$("#1234").replaceWith('<div id="1234" class="tooltip-enabled"</div>');` the binding is lost.

I know I can rebind it after `replaceWith`, but I'd like to avoid this if I can (mainly so that I don't need to remember to do it each time, or which options I've set!). Is there a way of doing this, sort of like how `.on()` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain `tooltip()` method:

```
$("#1234").replaceWith('<div id="1234" class="tooltip-enabled"></div>').tooltip();
```

Better yet, if you are just adding a class here, use `addClass()`:

```
$("#1234").addClass("tooltip-enabled").tooltip();
```

---

If you want to do event delegation, use `selector` option [(demo)](http://bootply.com/65075):

```
$("body").tooltip({
  selector: ".tooltip-enabled"
});

$("#1234").addClass("tooltip-enabled");
```

Comment: I think the problem that I have with this approach is that I have to remember to re-instantiate the tooltip (as well as specific settings for it) at the point that I replace the div, which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: that looks like the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `container` option. It will attach tooltip to another object and will react to DOM changes much like delegated events:

```
$('.tooltip-enabled').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: but doesn't that just affect the tooltip itself, not the trigger?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get your question. what is the trigger?

Answer (score -1):

try passing '{live: true}' as parameter to the function, eg

```
$('.tooltip-enabled').tooltip({live: true})
```

as a parameter to the function

Comment: this option does not exist

Comment: i have used a customized bootstrap js. i havent done the customization but faced the same issue. i solved it as $('a[rel=twipsy], .quickhelp').twipsy({live: true});

Comment: This is an option from Twipsy plugin that doesn't exist in Bootstrap's Tooltip: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js#L340